# python can't remove a file after closing it, "being used by another process"

Tags: python

I am trying to remove a file after reading from it, but getting "WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

```
file = open(self.filePath)
for line in file:
        #do things
file.close()

os.remove(self.filePath) #throws error

os.rename(self.filePath, self.filePath + "old") #throws same error
```

any ideas??

thank you!

UPDATE:
i just restarted my (windows 7) box, started eclipse, moved os.remove("c:\file\file.txt") to the first line of my script, ran and got the same error.

UPDATE 2:
i used windows explorer to navigate to the file.. first time I couldn't delete it, it was being used by "System".  second attempt the delete worked fine.  the file is no longer there.  now when I run 
    os.remove("c:\file\file.txt")
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\file\file.txt'
then i look in windows explorer and the file is back, empty.  i can delete in explorer, then when i run the script to remove, it throws the error (and creates the empty file).  any idea what could be going on here?

UPDATE 3:
i am an idiot.
i was opening the file in the initialization of an object
when i tested by moving the "remove" to top of script, i should have put it at the top, not after creating my objects

sorry for taking your time, i've been working on something all weekend that's due tomorrow and panicked when it wouldn't run

Comment: Grab Process Explorer or something similar and try taking a look at what actually has the file open.

Comment: If you try to remove the file before opening it, does that work?

Comment: Is filePath a directory?

Comment: filePath is a text file.  i have written to it fine, just can't remove it

Comment: Hard-coding file paths is not a good idea at the best of times. Worse: great care needs to be taken on Windows where the backslash is overloaded (path separator and escape character). `os.remove("c:\file\file.txt")` should be `os.remove(r"c:\file\file.txt")` or `os.remove("c:\\file\\file.txt")` or `os.remove("c:/file/file.txt")`

Answer (score 10):

Another *possibility* is that a virus checker still has the file open at the time you try to delete or rename it. This doesn't happen often but when it does, it's really annoying to track down.

Comment: I've also seen virus checkers screw up code like this a lot. My suggestion is to catch WindowsError and if it failed because the file is in use, sleep for a short time and try again.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)(easier) or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what program has the file open.

*(as suggested by [Anon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224346/anon))*

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem right now with an access-AB. Process Explorer shows that .. 'python.exe' is using the file that I wish to delete. I can not kill Python. It is an annoying solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possible reasons for this. However, the most likely one is that you have a directory window open that contains the file, or that such a window was closed recently and Windows has yet to flush the directory from its cache. Try closing any directory window that you were looking in and try again.

Comment: hi.. please see update to my quesion.  i just restarted windows, opened eclipse, moved the os.remove line to top of script, ran and got same error.  didn't open explorer at all this windows session