# Removing non-alphanumeric characters from filenames and rename in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get rid of non alphanumeric characters within a source folder and rename any files with non-alphanumeric characters to versions without by using this code. However every time I run the module I get this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tempstore\Filescan1", line 18, in <module>
    os.rename(filename,newfilename)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Help Please?

```
os.chdir("C:\\tempstore\\source")
file_list = glob.glob("*.mpg*")
for filename in file_list:
    if re.search('[^A-Za-z0-9._ ]+',filename,re.U) is not None:
        print filename + " <--Dodgy File"
        print re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z+_. ]+','-',filename)+ " <--Fixed File"
        newfilename =  re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z+_. ]+','-',filename)
        os.rename(filename,newfilename)
    elif re.search('[^A-Za-z0-9._ ]+',filename,re.U) is None:
        print filename +" <-- Normal File"
        unchanged_list = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9._ ]+','_',filename)
        print unchanged_list
```

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh, but try to put some effort indenting, it was a complete mess. See if this makes sense now or just fix it as it best goes

Comment: Sorry bout that, this is my first time posting here so I was a little bit confused

Comment: print `filename` and `newfilename` and look at [what process uses these files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1856857/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The reason the error came up was that windows will not let you edit files in an open directory and my program was opening the directory to edit the files. Catch-22 really, you can't edit files in an open directory but you have to open the directory to edit the files. 
I have moved the files using shutil.copy and then renaming them and this works fine
Apologies for my noob behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your anti-virus software or at least set "On Access" scanning to Off.  I would also suggest using re.sub to generate `newfilename` then using that for both printing out and the rename i.e. :

```
    print re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z+_. ]+','-',filename)+ " <--Fixed File"
    newfilename =  re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z+_. ]+','-',filename)
```

should read:

```
    newfilename =  re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z+_. ]+','-',filename)
    print 'Renaming to:', newfilename
```

and getting rid of the last two lines of your example.

Comment: My python is not brilliant(as you may have guessed) tbh I had not used regular expressions until yesterday, can you please put an example of what you mean?

Comment: Edited the answer above.

Comment: I have tried this but am still getting the error message, antivirus is off. this is getting really frustrating!

Comment: What happens if you try renaming by hand - what happens, have you tried copy then delete instead of rename - did that work, has any other process actually got the file(s) open, have you tried restarting your computer to make _sure_ that there isn't a hung session that is causing the problem.