# How to close an HDF5 using low level Python API?

Tags: python, anaconda, hdf5, h5py

I was able to modify the cache settings of an HDF5 file by combining both the high and low level Python h5py API as defined in the following Stack Overflow question: [How to set cache settings while using h5py high level interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653259/how-to-set-cache-settings-while-using-h5py-high-level-interface/14656421?noredirect=1#comment67138276_14656421)

I am getting an error saying that the h5 file is still open when I try to rename the file. The Python "with" statement with the contextlib does not seem to be closing the file after the HDF5 writing operation is completed and the file is flushed. How can I make sure that the file is closed using either the low-level or high-level API? Could you please provide an example ?

```
import h5py
import contextlib
import os

filename = 'foo_2.h5'
propfaid = h5py.h5p.create(h5py.h5p.FILE_ACCESS)
settings = list(propfaid.get_cache())
settings[2] *= 5
propfaid.set_cache(*settings)

with h5py.File(filename, 'w') as hf:
    print 'file created'

with contextlib.closing(h5py.h5f.open(filename, fapl=propfaid)) as fid:

    f = h5py.File(fid)
    f.flush()

    # f.close() Seems to be working only in Python 3.4.3 but not in 2.7.7
    #and the "with contextlib.closing(...)  does not work on either version
    f.close()

os.rename(filename, 'foo_2.h5')
```

**Additional information:** 
**OS: Windows 

Python: 2.7.7 

Anaconda Distribution: 2.0.1 

H5py version: 2.3.0**

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Comment: You could get this error if somewhere else in the code the file is being
opened (but not closed). Or, if some other process (such as a [virus checker or
some other application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1856787/190597) has the file open.) You might try using [Unlocker or
Process Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1856857/190597) to see what
applications have the file open.  I don't see any error in the code you
posted. It, in itself, does not raise an error (at least not for me on linux).

Comment: I have added a working script for testing. Which version of Python are you running in your linux machine ?

Comment: Using `Ubuntu 14.04 / Python2.7.6 / h5py 2.2.1`, the `f.close()` raises `ValueError: not a file ID (Invalid arguments to routine: Inappropriate type)`. If I remove that line, the code you posted above runs without error (and succeeds at renaming the file, even if the original filename is different than the target name). The code also works using Python3.4.3 if I change `h5py.h5py.open(filename, ...)` to `h5py.h5py.open(filename.encode(), ...)`.

Comment: I am still having the same issue as user "Jim parker". I also tried to make the script sleep, using  time.sleep(), for a minute before the rename operation and it still throws the same error. I am testing with the same script that is being posted.

Comment: You may wish to raise this as a new issue [here](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues).

Comment: Thank you. I have opened the issue [Unable to close an HDF5 using low level Python API](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/761)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for .close()

```
f.close()
```

Although looking closer, I'm not sure why contextlib.closing(...) didn't work.

I edited the line involving contextlib to be:

```
with contextlib.closing(h5py.File(filename, fapl=propfaid)) as fid:
```

and removed

```
f = h5py.File(fid)
```

Afterwards, I could check that fid was closed and renaming file worked as expected.

```
print fid
<Closed HDF5 file>

os.rename(filename, 'foo2.hdf5')
```

No errors and check of directory shows the new name

Comment: I tried using f.close() but it didn't work. It throws an error with the fid.

Comment: It worked for user unutbu but I am still having the same problem as you.

Comment: @zd5151  I made some changes to your code as reflected in my answer.  That code works for me using python 2.7.11 and h5py 2.5.0